# Numpy Overflow in calculations disrupting code

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, runtime-error

I am trying to train a neural network in Python 3.7. For this, I am using Numpy to perform calculations and do my matrix multiplications. I find this error

`RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply` (when I am multiplying matrices)

This, in turn, results in `nan` values, which raises errors like

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply`

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sign`

Now, I have seen many answers related to this question, all explaining why this happens. But I want to know, "How do I solve this problem?". I have tried using the default `math` module, but that still doesn't work and raises errors like

`TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

I know I can use `for` loops to do the multiplications, but that is computationally   very expensive, and also lengthens and complicates the code a lot. Is there any solution to this problem? Like doing something with Numpy (I am aware that there are ways to handle exceptions, but not solve them), and if not, then perhaps alternative to Numpy, which doesn't require me to change my code much?

I don't really mind if the precision of my data is compromised a bit. (If it helps the dtype for the matrices is `float64`)

**EDIT:**
Here is a dummy version of my code:

```
import numpy as np
network = np.array([np.ones(10), np.ones(5)])
for i in range(100000):
    for lindex, layer in enumerate(network):
        network[lindex] *= abs(np.random.random(len(layer)))*200000
```

I think the overflow error occurs when I am adding large values to the network.

Comment: what's the size of your matrices?

Comment: sometimes 2, sometimes 3 dimensional

Comment: @brainfuck4d I think the details I have provided are sufficient, basically, overflow error occurs and I do not know how to get my result, and overcome the error, and my code is quite big, so it would confuse many people

Comment: I don't think this is a site where people get confused by some code. A minimal working example would help the community to solve your problem.

Comment: @brainfuck4d But, I don't feel comfortable, giving away my hard-worked code, open on the internet

Comment: That's why I asked for a *minimal* working example. Can't help if there is nothing to correct

Comment: Have you tried building 64 bit numpy from source or using one of the distros of 64 np available out there.

Comment: If you actually want people to help you, just posting a bounty isn't going to cut it. You've already had two other people tell you the same thing in the comments: there just aren't enough details in your question (regardless of how you may feel about it). You're going to have to share at least a little bit of your code. If that makes you uncomfortable, you can always write up a simpler dummy version of your problem that hides all of the details (see [this doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for suggestions on how to do that). It just has to reproduce the same error.

Comment: Alright, great! Example code. Now we're getting somewhere. Good for you for figuring out a dummy version. However, your code executes just fine and doesn't produce an error, so it's still not enough for anyone to actually help you.

Comment: If you think that the error occurs when you "add large values to the network", you're going to have to figure out how to incorporate those large values into your example code. Essentially, nobody is going to know how to fix your broken code unless you post some broken code. Or, you could just bite the bullet and post the buggy section of your actual code. I imagine it'd make life easier for everyone, yourself included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem I too have faced with my neural network while using ReLu activators because of the infinite range on the positive side. There are two solutions to this problem:

A) Use another activation function: atan,tanh,sigmoid or any other one with limited range

However if you do not find those suitable:

B)Dampen the ReLu activations. This can be done by scaling down all values of the ReLu and ReLu prime function. Here's the difference in code:

```
##Normal Code
def ReLu(x,derivative=False):
    if derivative:
        return 0 if x<0 else 1
    return 0 if x<0 else x

##Adjusted Code
def ReLu(x,derivative=False):
    scaling_factor = 0.001
    if derivative:
        return 0 if x<0 else scaling_factor
    return 0 if x<0 else scaling_factor*x
```

Since you are willing to compromise on the precision this is a perfect solution for you! In the ending, you can multiply by the inverse of the scaling_factor to get the approximate solution- approximate because of rounding discrepancies.